# What is the proper method to stop loading a Flex Module before it has completely loaded?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, module

I seem to recall that Loader.unload() could once be used to stop loading a swf before it had finished loading. I can no longer find documentation or the blog where I read this.  Perhaps it was an unofficial feature.  Anyhow, IModuleInfo, returned by ModuleManager.getModule() has an unload() method.  If I want to halt loading a Flex Module that is in progress, do I just call iModuleInfo_instance.unload()?

Answer (score 1):

Listen for the `progress` event on the `ModuleLoader` ([reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/modules/ModuleLoader.html#event:progress)).  Then `unLoad`.